# Load data from Azure PostgreSQL to Azure Analysis Services (AAS)

Tags: postgresql, azure, datasource, azure-analysis-services

I have a Azure database for PostgreSQL and want to set up my Azure Analysis Service with this Postgres on Azure as datasource.
**I'm not sure whether PostgreSQL on Azure is supported by AAS?** I am getting the below error when trying to connect:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSfMt.png)

I tried with the below extension, but installing it did not resolve the issue:
[Npgsql installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9mq9.png)

My assumption is that **I need to install the on-premise gateway to be able to connect this Azure PostgreSQL db** **- can anybody confirm** this is the right direction and will resolve the connection issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure whether PostgreSQL on Azure is supported by AAS? I need to install the on-premise gateway to be able to connect this Azure PostgreSQL db - can anybody confirm this is the right direction and will resolve the connection issue?

According to [KranthiPakala](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53644/azure-analysis-service-use-postgresql-as-data-sour.html):

- Azure Database for PostgreSQL is [not a supported data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource#azure-data-sources) of AAS.
- You can connect to **on-prem PostgreSQL** as a data source for import or in-memory tabular models. In order to do this, select the ODBC data source option(start a new import connection , choose ODBC option, then pick the ODBC source name) and AAS will treat it like SQL Server.

References: [Data sources supported in Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource#other-data-sources) and [Specify provider data sources in tabular 1400 and higher model projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource#specify-provider-data-sources-in-tabular-1400-and-higher-model-projects)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a response. So there is no way to connect the Azure Database for PostgreSQL from AAS? I don't have the on-prem PostgreSQL so seems the second option wouldn't work for me.

Comment: According to [Data sources supported in Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource), as of now, **there is no way** to connect the Azure Database for **PostgreSQL as a data source** of AAS, **only on-prem PostgreSQL** is possible.